# error NG8001, selector "app-all-recipes" is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material

I wanted to use component from one module in another module but i've bumped into this error. At first i have thought that there might be a typo in the selector name or stuff like that but it was not the case. I've tried other things such as exporting and importing the module but i couldn't really solve it.
Here is the error message:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR12i.png)
As well as the folder structure
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ1SR.png)

My intention was to have AllRecipesComponent placed below the toolbar in main-page.component.html but it returns an error that the selector is not an known element.

```
<mat-toolbar class="main-toolbar">
  <button mat-icon-button class="main-toolbar-icon">
    <mat-icon>forest</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <span class="main-toolbar-title">Angular</span>
  <span class="main-toolbar-spacer"></span>
  <nav mat-tab-nav-bar class="main-toolbar-nav">
    <a mat-tab-link routerLink="new-recipe" disabled>New</a>
    <a mat-tab-link routerLink="login">Login</a>
    <a mat-tab-link routerLink="register">Register</a>
  </nav>
</mat-toolbar>
<app-all-recipes></app-all-recipes>
```

I am declaring two components in recipes.module.ts and exporting the one i wish to use in a different module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';

import { AllRecipesComponent } from './pages/all-recipes/all-recipes.component';
import { NewRecipeComponent } from './pages/new-recipe/new-recipe.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [NewRecipeComponent, AllRecipesComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, MatDividerModule, MatGridListModule, MatCardModule],
  exports: [AllRecipesComponent],
})
export class RecipesModule {}
```

But it also didn't work so i have tried to import the RecipesModule directly in main.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MainPageComponent } from './pages/main-page/main-page.component';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';

import { RecipesModule } from '../recipes/recipes.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MainPageComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    RecipesModule
  ],
})
export class MainModule {}
```

At this point im kinda stuck and i couldn't find a solution in the internet on my own so i'm posting it here in case someone had similiar error.

Comment: The code seems correct. Sometimes, you have to kill ng process, and rerun `npm start`. If it still doesn't work, can you double check your `AllRecipesComponent`'s selector is actually `app-all-recipes` ?

Comment: Selector looks fine and i've tried to rerun it a bunch of times but it didn't really work, it seems like i'm gonna have dive a little bit deeper into that

Comment: are you using lazy loading ?

Comment: By lazy loading you mean using loadChildren in routes? In that case no i am using regular one with components, can switching to lazy loading actually help?

Comment: lazy loading could explain the issue, so no (I had the exact same issue when implementing the lazy-loading: I imported my module twice. Once in the route, once in the AppModule)

Comment: It looks like importing the module in AppModule was the solution for that, i don't know why i did not tried it before. Thanks